# How add attribute to image

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I want to add attribute to image

[This is example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYXNq.png)

But now I don't know what file I should to do?

If alt = "Hello" so title = "Hello"

I want automatically to change title reference by alt.

thank you so much.